# How to kill command line server for IE server in webdriver

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Please guide me how to kill instances of IE driver . After i run test and on its completion browser is getting quit since i have used driver.quit().But found that instances are still up while cross checking in the task manager.

**skelton of code:**

```java
driver=new InternetExplorerDriver(); //calling IE driver 
testRun(); // run my test                                                                                          
driver.quit();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried driver.close(); - http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html

Comment: @aimbire The `close()` method is absolutely **not** guaranteed to shutdown IEDriverServer.exe instances. The `quit()` method is the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

I've a method for you,

```
public void ieKiller() throws Exception
{
  final String KILL = "taskkill /IM ";
  String processName = "IEDriverServer.exe"; //IE process
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(KILL + processName); 
  Wait(3000); //Allow OS to kill the process
}
```

[source](http://bharath-marrivada.blogspot.ch/2012/01/webdriverselenium-killterminate.html)